# Which of these two definitions is better or safer?

Tags: c

```
char* varc = "ALICE";
```

```
char varl[] = "ALICE";
```

```
char* vars = (char*)calloc(6,sizeof(char));
strcpy(vars,"ALICE");
```

Which of the above definitions should I use more?

Comment: It depends on what you're going to do with the data.

Comment: `strcpy(vars,"ALICE");` is UB when `vars == NULL`.

Comment: By the way, you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or related functions like `calloc`).

Answer (score 4):

```
char* varc = "ALICE";
```

This is a pointer to a CONSTANT (fixed) string, you cannot change the characters, so it should be:

```
const char* varc = "ALICE";
```

---

```
char varl[] = "ALICE";
```

This text can be changed after declaration, but it has a fixed size of 6-bytes.

---

```
char* vars = (char*)calloc(6,sizeof(char));
strcpy(vars,"ALICE");
```

With this one, you can choose the size of the buffer before putting any text in it, and you can over-allocate space if you might later want to put a longer string (`"SAMANTHA"`) in it.

Overall, do not think in terms of *"which one should I use more?"*.

Think in terms of *"What are the limitations and abilities of each technique, and which one is **correct** for this specific use-case"*

Comment: With the last one you have to remember to call `free(vars)`